# Is there a way to only acces one collider when there are many colliders with the same tag?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, tags, raycasting

I have a script that moves the object you're touching to the position of your finger, it's based on a tag so when I touch an object with the tag all the objects with the same tag move to that position. Is there a way to make only the one I'm touching move?

The Script

````
 {
     void FixedUpdate()
     {
         if (Input.touchCount > 0)
         {            
             RaycastHit2D hitInformation = Physics2D.Raycast(Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.GetTouch(0).position),Camera.main.transform.forward);            
                 if (hitInformation.collider.gameObject.tag == "RocketPrefab")
                 {                    
                     Vector3 touchPosition = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.GetTouch(0).position);
                     touchPosition.z = -4;
                     transform.position = touchPosition;
                     Debug.Log(touchPosition);

                 }                            
         }
     }
 } ```
````

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can access the object your Raycast is touching with `hitInformation.collider.gameObject`.

From the code that I'm seeing, I think this should work:

```
     void FixedUpdate()
     {
         if (Input.touchCount > 0)
         {            
             RaycastHit2D hitInformation = Physics2D.Raycast(Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.GetTouch(0).position),Camera.main.transform.forward);            
                 if (hitInformation.collider.gameObject.tag == "RocketPrefab")
                 {                    
                     Vector3 touchPosition = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.GetTouch(0).position);
                     touchPosition.z = -4;
                     hitInformation.collider.gameObject.transform.position = touchPosition;
                     Debug.Log(touchPosition);
                 }                            
         }
     }
```

Comment: Instead of the fix value of `touchPosition.z = -4;` you could try to use the more general `touchPosition.z = hitInformation.distance;`

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming the script is on the parent of all "RocketPrefab" GameObjects and you are then moving them all with the line `transform.position = touchPosition;`

With that assumption... to get the specific one that the raycast hit you would need to edit the script to move the `collider.gameObjct.transform`not just `transform`

Edited FixedUpdate

```
void FixedUpdate()
{
    if (Input.touchCount > 0)
    {            
        RaycastHit2D hitInformation = Physics2D.Raycast(Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.GetTouch(0).position),Camera.main.transform.forward);            
        if (hitInformation.collider.gameObject.tag == "RocketPrefab")
        {                    
            Vector3 touchPosition = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.GetTouch(0).position);
            touchPosition.z = -4;
            hitInformation.collider.gameObject.transform.position = touchPosition; // Note this line and how it targets the specific transform
            Debug.Log(touchPosition);
        }                            
    }
}
```

Comment: Same answer as the first one

Comment: It said his was posted 9 seconds ago when the page refreshed after I posted this answer and as mine explained the issue more I left it up.